# prcomp, Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric, when my data is numeric?

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to do PCA on a set of data using prcomp

```
SS.chem<-read.csv("PCASS3.csv")
SS.pca <- prcomp(SS.chem,
             center = TRUE,
             scale. = TRUE)
```

which returns the following error

```
> SS.pca <- prcomp(SS.chem,
+                  center = TRUE,
+                  scale. = TRUE)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

However, when I test to make sure my data are numeric, they... are?

```
sapply(SS.chem, class)
Capture.zone       X_.18O.NO3       X_.15N.NO3            NO3.T 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
   WellDepth          PopDens              Pop       DepthToUfa 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
        SOM.            Clay.     ConfineThick            LUDom 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
  ostdscount              Ag.          Barren.          Forest. 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
Transportation. UplandNonforest.           Urban.         Wetland. 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
GolfCourses. ImprovedPasture.      FieldCrops.          Citrus. 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
 Ornamental.       HorseFarm.          Sewage. 
   "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"
```

Is there something I'm missing? Why is it still giving me this error?

Edit: Here are a few lines of my data

```
> str(SS.chem)
List of 27
$ Capture.zone    : num [1:48] 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 100 2 1000 2 2 ...
$ X_.18O.NO3      : num [1:48] 9.23 7.74 10.75 5.37 0 ...
$ X_.15N.NO3      : num [1:48] 10.67 6.78 9.53 7.88 3.03 ...
$ NO3.T           : num [1:48] 0.49 0 0.01 0.38 0.04 0 0.02 1.73 0.25 ...
$ WellDepth       : num [1:48] 0 190 132 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ PopDens         : num [1:48] 246.092 1.102 21.331 246.092 0.359 ...
$ Pop             : num [1:48] 313.417 1.404 27.166 313.417 0.457 ...
$ DepthToUfa      : num [1:48] 121.9 107.9 79.1 121.9 36.4 ...
$ SOM.            : num [1:48] 1.12 1.23 1.23 1.12 60 ...
$ Clay.           : num [1:48] 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3 ...
$ ConfineThick    : num [1:48] 85.1 91.4 61.7 85.1 0 ...
```

Comment: Can u show few lines of your data?

Comment: Posted an update with some of the data

Comment: The structure of the data shows it is a list, convert to data frame first.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to a data frame.

```
# Example data:

ls <- list(Capture.zone=c(1000, 1000 ,1000, 1000, 1000),
X_.18O.NO3 = c( 9.23, 7.74, 10.75, 5.37, 0),
X_.15N.NO3 = c(10.67, 6.78, 9.53, 7.88, 3.03),
NO3.T  = c(0.49, 0, 0.01, 0.38, 0.04),
WellDepth = c( 0, 190, 132, 0, 0))

#convert to a data frame
df <- data.frame(ls)

#get the pricipal components
prcomp(df)

#               PC1         PC2         PC3          PC4         PC5
#Capture.zone  0.000000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.000000000   1
#X_.18O.NO3    0.023172366  0.77806115 -0.58173783  0.235934281   0
#X_.15N.NO3    0.003266792  0.62719370  0.70307503 -0.335116238   0
#NO3.T        -0.001764784  0.02911366  0.40880900  0.912153762   0
#WellDepth     0.999724590 -0.02003257  0.01190818 -0.002763407   0
```